# Cant find Timer Account SharePoint 2013

Tags: central-administration

To solve a problem in upgrading to Enterprise I am trying to learn/find how to do the following. I can not find on the internet where that is for Sharepoint 2013

When I changed the Timer account to a domain admin account, the upgrade ran just fine.  So now I'm a bit confused by that, but I have Enterprise Sharepoint.

Comment: What is your question? Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The Timer account referenced in the statement is in the Services under Administrative Tools on the Windows Machine that is hosting Sharepoint. There if I change the user to the machine account I can upgrade to Enterprise